# Java Spring authentication using databsase, how to remove role model?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc

I have Spring authentication project and I want to use it like template for my future work.
There is connection with database (mysql).
The problem is -- this project includes Role Model. There are 2 roles: ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN But I don't want to use it.

How can I remove this thing from my project, and use authentication only by checking login and password from one table in database?

For attachment - there is part of spring security xml file:

```
<http auto-config="true">

    <remember-me data-source-ref="dataSource" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/accessDenied" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/user" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <form-login login-page='/login' default-target-url="/"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" username-parameter="user_login"
        password-parameter="password_login" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="jdbcGroupsImpl"
    class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
    <beans:property name="enableGroups" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="enableAuthorities" value="false" />
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="jdbcGroupsImpl" />
</authentication-manager>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So you want to have one type of user that can log in and do stuff ?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the 'intercept-url' tags? That's the only point where spring ask for roles

Answer (score 2):

Assign any role in the authentication provider and change the access level to "isAuthenticated".

For example:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/user" access="isAuthenticated" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have just one user role like  ROLE_USER and authenticate them against your DB utilizing a form. Security xml can be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="my.pachage"/>

<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
<security:form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/login"
       username-parameter="userName" 
       password-parameter="password" default-target-url="/login/"
       authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"/>

<security:intercept-url pattern="/yourURL/*" access="hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll"/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
       <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="jdbcGroupsImpl"/>
</security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

and in you controller authenticate the user by fetching authentication info from a LDAP or a DB.